# How do I stop a flask app that was started from within another python program when the original program is closed?

Tags: python, windows, flask, subprocess

I start a Python program, then this program starts a Flask app.  When I close the Python program I want the Flask program that it opened to also close.  Ideally, if the Python program crashed or was not shutdown correctly, the Flask program should also be closed.

Note I currently open the flask program from python program using

```
subprocess.Popen(r'python BUAC_app.py ....
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a Minimal Working Example and what you have tried to far, so we have something to work with.

Comment: You could look into using supervisord for managing the subprocesses with stopasgroup=true

Comment: Thanks all.  I ended up combining my flask app into my main python app and used threading.  A lot easier than trying to stop a separate flask app.  Plenty of examples of flask and threading on SO.  :)